# How to fix php code to transfer data from html form to a database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to get data from a form into a database, have searched all the answers and code on yours and other websites but none of them work.

It is connecting to the database OK, but keep getting an error message when submitting the form.

Thanks

My form is

```
<html><head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css" type="text/css">


<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<h1>A small example page to insert some data in to the MySQL database using 
PHP</h1>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br><br>

Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My PHP code is

```
<?php

$servername = "server";
$username = "username";
$password = "xxxx";
$database = "xxx_com";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
{
    $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];

    $dbh->query = "INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname)
    VALUES  ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]')";
}

if (!mysqli_query($user_info, $connect)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo “Your information was added to the database.”; 
mysqli_close($connect); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you post error message ?

Comment: Change the smart quotes in your echo to regular quotes, it will throw a parsing error. Also, you have unnecessary brackets after your mysqli_connect.

Comment: The post variable is wrong $_POST['first_name'] the input name is "fname" so the post variable need to be $_POST['fname']

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: `$conn !== $dbh`

Answer (score 0):

Your html form using

```
Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>

Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>
```

but your PHP get from

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
```

it should used the same name. Like

```
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lname'];
```

As mention by people comment, please learn how to avoid the SQL injection problem

Comment: Sorry, have just amended the code, it is still not working.

Comment: Also change 
    $dbh->query = "INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname)
    VALUES  ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]')"; to use your  variable instead getting from POST again.

Comment: The error message is This page isn’t working, HTTP error 500

Comment: I have changed the PHP code, it is now:                                                                                           $dbconnect=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];

Comment: Followed by 
    $query = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('".$first_name."','".$last_name."', '".$email."')";
 
 I get this error message in my database MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )